# libav use encoder private options instead

Tags: libav

I'm getting some errors building a tool that uses libav. The errors are about some struct field being deprecated.

```
AVCodecContext::intra_quant_bias’ is deprecated
```

The error is coming from this piece of code:

```
vcodec_context->intra_quant_bias
```

When I look in the libav documentation it just says to "use encoder private options instead", but I can't figure out how to do this.

**Does anybody know what this means and how to change that line?**

I've seen in the libav documentation that I could use a define to suppress those warnings, but I don't want to go that route I'd rather fix the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can set encoder private options by calling `av_opt_set` (according to your data type) on `vcodec_context` for each option you want to configure.

Example here (`video_codec_ctx` being an `AVCodecContext*`):

```
av_opt_set(video_codec_ctx->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
av_opt_set(video_codec_ctx->priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx->priv_data, "crf", 27, 0); // For integer values
av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx->priv_data, "bufsize", 100, 0);
av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx->priv_data, "keyint", fps, 0);
av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx->priv_data, "keyint_max", fps, 0);
av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx->priv_data, "g", 1, 0);
```

It's also possible to call `av_dict_set` on an `AVDictionary*` and let those options be handled in the moment you allocate the `AVCodecContext` by calling `avcodec_open2`:

```
AVDictionary* dict = NULL;
av_dict_set(&dict, "strict", "+experimental", 0);
avcodec_open2(video_codec_ctx, video_codec, &dict);
```